# Mojave - /Library/Webserver/Documents folder permisisons

Tags: macos, apache, permissions

I hope someone can help. I have apache running on my mac with my websites loacated at: /Library/Webserver/Documents/mywebsite

It works fine if I go to: http://mywebsite.localhost

... but everytime I try to edit a file in 'mywebsite' directory I get a "{filename} is a locked file and can only be viewed".

If I do a 'get info' on /Library/Webserver/Documents - the result is:

{myuser} : read & write
system : read & write
wheel : read only
everyone : read only

If I do a 'get info' on /Library/Webserver/Documents/mywebsite/index.php - the result is:

{myuser} : Read & write
staff : Read only
everyone : read only

.. but it still says it's locked and read only?

I could move the site folder to /Users/{myuser}/Sites/mywebsite which fixes the problem of permissions but I don't want to have to go to:

http://localhost/~myuser/mywebsite

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1):

I moved the site folder to

```
/Users/{myuser}/Sites
```

which solved the permission problem then added the site to the httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Users/{myuser}/Sites/mywebsite"
ServerName mywebsite.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Which has solved the URL issue:

http://mywebsite.localhost

Comment: I have 2 directories under private/etc/apache2, /original and /extra directories having that file. Which one should I edit?

Comment: /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf